# Rails "Sometimes Has One" Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is probably a newbie question, but I can't seem to think of a good solution. I have a `company` table that `has_many users through groups` that can also be administrators of the company (enabling them to edit the company but only one company per user).

What's the best way to set this up in Rails?

I can't add an `admin` field to the user table, because it wouldn't discriminate which company he/she is administrating. But if I do a `company_id` field, what would that relationship look like in Rails (since it's a sort of `somtimes_has_one` relationship!). I could leave it without a relationship, but that doesn't seem proper...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does every company have an admin user?

Comment: Yes, every company would have an admin user, but it also has several normal users. So, is there a way to do a "has_one where" type relationship?

Comment: In that case, why not put a AdminUserId field on the companies table that describes which user is that company's admin?  (I'm just learning rails so I'm not sure what the magic rails syntax would be)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to hook that up with Rails. I know there can be a `has_one user` in the company table, but what would then be in the user table to go the other way (e.g. so I could look up users that belong to a company, but can't use belongs_to because not all users do belong_to one, only admin users).

Comment: You could actually use `belongs_to` here - it is the appropriate counterpart to `has_one`.  Just be careful when you're coding with that association, because the returned value is likely to be `nil`.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a user which might belong to a company, and if it does, it might actually administer it.

You could setup `Group` to have for example, `company_id`, `user_id` and an `admin` field (this way you get to know which users belong to which company, and if they also administrate that company)

For a user to belong to just one company you could add a validation for uniqueness per two columns (`company_id` and `user_id`)

You could get one company's administrators by doing

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_many :users, through: :groups
  has_many :administrators, through: :groups, source: :user, conditions: ["groups.admin = ?", true]
end
```

and call `company.administrators` or `company.users` for all users

You could also do something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :group
  has_one :company, through: :group
  has_one :administered_company, through: :group, source: :company, conditions: ["groups.admin = ?", true]
end
```

so you can call `user.company` or `user.administered_company`

and so on...

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Didn't know about the `source` and ability to use `conditions` in a has_many through relationship!

Comment: I just had one question. I'm getting a strange SQL error when trying to create a new company, saying: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.group_id: SELECT  1 FROM "users" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "users"."group_id" = "groups"."id" WHERE "groups"."company_id" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = 1 AND (groups.admin = 't') LIMIT 1`. Do you know why this is being thrown by chance?

Comment: Oops, nevermind, it's because I'm using CanCan and it's searching for something that doesn't exist!